# GPIO's firing every ~3 milliseconds

Tags: gpio, electronics, javascript

I'm currently building a project using [adafruits arcade buttons](https://www.adafruit.com/products/473), and seem to be having a bit of an electrical problem.

Using a  Raspberry Pi 2 , and after confirming that wires aren't touching in places they're not supposed to be, I attached the wires from a single button to my 5v pin and GPIO pin 23 (no breadboard or anything at the moment). I plug my RPi's power in to my laptop without a charger plugged in and run the following javascript code (Nodejs 0.12.7).

```
var Gpio = require('onoff').Gpio;
var moment = require('moment');

var firstButton = new Gpio(23, 'in', 'both', {debounceTimeout: 250});
firstButton.watch(function (err, value) {
  console.log(moment() + ' Button Pressed | ' + value)
});
```

Everything works exactly as predicted! When I push the button, it's console logged once with value 1 then 0. However now the problem, if I plug it in to my USB power adapter on my power bar, the button starts firing every 1 to 3 milliseconds without touching it, logging value 0. It also rarely accepts when I push the button at all, guessing because the event is being spammed.

To add to the issue, if I plug the Raspberry Pi in to my laptop again, but then an HDMI TV, the same issue happens.

What is it I'm doing wrong here? I'm new to messing with electrical. Do I need a breadboard with a couple other of little things to prevent this from happening when plugged in to the wall? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the rating (output volts and amps) on the USB adapter?   Note your laptop port will only promise 500 mA, which is borderline.  This may explain why the added stress of the HDMI connection causes a problem.

Comment: 5V, 3.1A. Also have a 500ma, same issue.

And note, this also happens without the HDMI but plugged in to the wall.

Comment: NEVER connect 5V to a Pi gpio.  You will damage the gpio and the Pi.  Please post a photo of your connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I attached the wires from a single button to my 5v pin and GPIO pin 23

The GPIOs on the Pi are on a regulated 3.3V circuit.  This is true whether they are set as outputs or inputs.  If you attach them directly to a 5V source, including the pi itself, you may damage them permanently.

This doesn't explain why the pin fluctuates with the button up *unless* it's because you already damaged it.   Try using a different pin and 3.3V **but you need to use a resistor in a button circuit**.  There are many examples and explanations of this online if you search for "raspberry pi gpio button".